# Whoami and xargs

Tags: xargs

I need help trying run whoami and get userid and then run df -k to find all filesystem that are own by userid.

The following command I have, but does not work.

```
whoami | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -I '{}' df -k | grep '{}'
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here. Filesystems aren't owned by users.

Comment: For example, I am in login as john on a servers. Then I want to run whoami  to get current userid (which is john), then I want to run df -k | grep john. This will give me all filesystems that are own by john.  So, I want use xargs. Basically run whoami then redirect the output to df -k command.

Answer (score 0):

It was easier then that I thought. Following command works

```
df -k | grep  `whoami`
```

This will show all filesystems that userid who run the command.